# Why do I have a read-only NFS4?

Tags: nfs

NFS SERVER side:

```
[USER@NFSSERVER ~]$ cat /etc/exports
/var/foo/logs 10.75.16.4(ro,sync)
/var/foobar 10.100.102.0/24(rw,sync)  
[USER@NFSSERVER ~]$
```

NFS CLIENT side:

```
[root@NFSCLIENT ~]# grep nfs /etc/fstab 
10.100.102.34:/var/foobar /var/foobar nfs auto 0 0
[root@NFSCLIENT ~]#
```

NFS CLIENT is in the 10.100.102.0/24

Other NFS CLIENT can write to this dir.

The problem:

```
[root@NFSCLIENT foobar]# touch testing
touch: cannot touch `testing': Permission denied
[root@NFSCLIENT foobar]#
```

**Question**: Why don't we have permission to write? FS mounted as RW, both are RHEL 6, NFSv4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you export your filesystem without the `no_root_squash` option, your root user ID gets mapped to "anonymous" or "nobody" on the server side. That effectively denies you permissions to write. It's a common-sense default to guard against SUID-type attacks through NFS mounts, but it can cause issues like this for those unfamiliar with it. You can access the NFs mount normally as a non-root user (UID != 0), or you can add the `no_root_squash` option to `/etc/exports`, re-export from the server, and re-mount on the client to get permission to write to the mounted filesystem as root on the client.